# What is the image format to display a 3D object in openGL?

Tags: ios, iphone, opengl-es

I'm going to start a project for Augumented Reality, before that I want to know what type/format of images are required to display the images as 3D object.Note: I'm going to use ARToolKit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `.dae` file for your 3D object and `SceneKit` to add it to your app.

Comment: Thanks. DAE file would contains 3d objects in the form of binary data

Comment: According to the documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/SceneKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html you should use COLLADA 3D objects (`.dae`). You just need the proper software to create the file and then you can access the objects from XCode

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL puts no constraints whatsoever on the file formats of your geometry data. As long as you can write or find some preexisting a parser for the format you'd like to read (and the internal data structure can be fed to OpenGL efficiently) you can use it.

Keep in mind that scenes are usually represented as geometry composed of meshes made up of triangles, which is usually not called "3D images". A "3D image" would be an actual image, consisting of volumetric data, think MRT or CT scan (or similar).